# Karma test TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property using Phantom JS 2.1.1

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

We are facing `TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property` with Karma tests on `httpBackend.flush()` call.

Phantom JS version - 2.1.1.

Angular JS ,Angular mocks version- 1.2.26

Below is the source code :

```
    httpBackend.when('POST','/api/****/')
    .respond(200,response);

    spyOn(obj, 'event1');

    scope.requestMethod(mock);

    httpBackend.flush();
    expect(obj.event1).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Any pointers on this issue is really appreciated.